# javacv runnable.jar have error when running it in rasberry pi

Tags: java, compilation, raspberry-pi, javacv

i have compile GUI javacv code in windows and it run ok with no problem and when i run the runnable.jar file in raspberry pi it give me this error and doesnt run

java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that an opencv.jar file is missing from your raspberry pi's classpath (or is the wrong version).

See if you have the latest version, and/or the linux version needed for the PI*, then either include both in the /lib of your project or make sure it is added to the java classpath on your PI.

*The lib you use on your windows development environment is not compatible with the PI. You need a linux version (or the Android version, depending which is running on the PI) for the PI, and a windows version to run on Windows.

These can be downloaded from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files

Comment: can i export the gui to run in rasberry pi without install opencv in rasberrypi as it take 4 to 5 hours setup i want do all thing in my computer and run it in rasberry pi

Comment: Are you building the final output as a jar file?  You could unzip the opencv.jar file INTO your source code, then when the jar builds all the code from opencv will be in your jar.

Comment: this all is done i have import javacv-bin,javacv-cppjars inside libraries of my project which contains opencv libraries but also not run in raspberry pi but run in windows ok

Comment: Just because you have import and the classes in your lib isn't enough, you actually have to supply the class files that are being represented BY the import.  Basically, the version of Java you have on your PI does not have a the same libraries.  If you're building a jar (Are you?) then most likely the packages that are in your lib directory are being used to compile but they must also be there at run time.

Comment: You either need to include the classes from the lib packages IN your jar file, or you have to make sure those lib packages on deploy to the PI as well (and are thus on the classpath).

Comment: i have  run my .jar file using this command java -classpath '....' -jar proj.jar which include the classpath of my lib and also doesnt work :)

Comment: Then that would mean that the lib you're using isn't compatible with the PI. You need a linux version (or the Android version, which OS are you running?) for the PI, and a windows version to run on Windows.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/

Comment: i use compatible lib and compile it in raspberry pi and the error is change to HIGHGUI ERROR: V$L/V$L2:VIDIOC_CROPCAP

Comment: After as google search I found: 

If you are using prebuilt binaries, they may be built without v4l support. Try to build your own OpenCV with v4l checked. And of course before that install v4l with development files. You can follow [this](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/) tutorial with how to install required dependicies explanied.